# Is it safe to run code code received via ajax?

Tags: javascript, security

I wrote the [script](https://github.com/sydes/sydes/blob/master/system/assets/js/ajaxRouter.js#L34) that can execute code received via ajax from the server. And I don't know may anyone exploit it? Do I need to add a check that the request is for the same domain?

Comment: As you are executing it client side, the client has 100% control on what you sent. The question is, is your data protected?

Comment: use eval is bad idea:(

Comment: @Mistalis how I can protect? No idea about this

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón why? It is useful

Comment: because your are given permision to any code to execute like own code in your own page, in your own server, in your own machine

Answer (score 0):

In theory client trusts the data you provide, that includes code both within your application as well as dynamic stuff client gets over ajax. 
Problems might arise, if somebody manages to spoof your server or perform man-in-the-middle attack and can start sending malicious code.
My suggestion would be - if you are in doubt if anyone can exploit it, it's most likely exploitable, since you have no idea what you are doing. Ergo - don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should secure the code that is being sent over AJAX, so it is not tampered with.

The code can be secured in different ways. For example HTTPS. Custom encryption can also be used for example Base64 encoding.

Comment: Can you suggest any way to encrypt with key on php and decrypt it on js? Base64 not suitable here I think.

Comment: Well base64 encoding is supported natively by both php and javascript. Javascript provides the functions atob and btoa for encoding and decoding base64 string (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob). Php provides the base64_encode and base64_decode functions. http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php